# How to change "Introduction" at the top in Documentation generated by the Postman?

Tags: postman, documentation, documentation-generation

Is it possible to change the name "Introduction" at the top of requests?

It's a documentation generated by Postman, i haven't access to the HTML code.

[image: Image of the problem]

I need to change this name, does anyone know how I do it?

Comment: You should be able to do this in the application, it will be under the `description` on the Collection.

Comment: In the `description` doesn't have nothing to change the "Introduction".

I think the "Introduction" is created with the documentation, because i not put there.

Comment: Not near my laptop to check this, yeah that should about right. When you create the docs via the `New > Create Documentation` flow, I believe that it's in there as the default description. Again, this is from memory and not checking it.

Comment: But it's possible change the name "Introduction" or not yet?

Answer (score 0):

Those headings are created when you go through the `+New > Documentation` flow.

They can be changed/deleted from here when you first create the Documentation.

[image]

If the Documentation has already been created - You can change the headings by editing the Collection.

[image]

Once the `Edit Collection` modal is open, you will find the details under the `Description` tab.

[image]

Comment: Can't remove the name *Introduction*, if we add only one item in the description, document displays two, introduction and another one that we have added. Check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82arL.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SLKq.png).

Comment: Thank You, my question finally have a answer hahahha. 


But in my case, i needed to delete or change the name Introduction, but he is default and not have how make this hahahhaha.


I hope that the Postman, in new atualizations , include a way of change it.

Comment: Feel free to submit a bug/feature request on the GH issue tracker https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues - Its the only way your hopes will be answered :)